# rails : How to omit a particular property from an array of objects in a JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to get a model that doesn't include the `id column`. I think that the method `select` allows this, but when I access models, I see the `id` field with `nil` value.

When I use:

```
module API
  class MyController < ActionController::API
    def index
      response = MyModel
                 .where("value > ?", 0)
                 .select('code','value')
      render json: response, status: 200
    end
```

When I inspect the result using each like this

MyModel
    .where("value > ?", 0)
    .select('code','value')
    .each{|m| puts m}

I get this

```
<MyModel id: nil, code: "110", value: 100>
<MyModel id: nil, code: "111", value: 100>
<MyModel id: nil, code: "112", value: 100>
```

and in my response I get this:

```
[{id: null, code: "110", value: 100},{id: null, code: "111", value: 100},{id: null, code: "112", value: 100}]
```

**How to omit the id column?**

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jordan I need return an array of `MyModel ` but without the id field included

Comment: Right, you said as much already. But what problem are you trying to solve? You want to "return an array," but to where? What is the use case? You've already succeeded in selecting only the `code` and `value` fields from the database, which is why the `id` attribute is `nil`.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: You didn't really answer any of my questions. Nevertheless, is this, perhaps, a hash that will be sent as a JSON response? Are you asking how to omit a particular property from an array of objects in a JSON response?

Comment: @jordan thanks for help me to articulate my question. In fact, my  question should be "how to omit a particular property from an array of objects in a JSON response?" i think

Comment: It would be worth your while to read this: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's something with the `puts` command. If you only do `Model.select(:attributes)`, it shouldn't return id column if it is not in the list (did the test here and works fine). I believe the puts command retrieve the object from database or something like that. By the way, you can override what is printed when you do `puts object` if you override the `to_s` method in the object class

Comment: this is not actual spot on answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, when using `#select` method, even if you are not using `id` in `select` method arguments, it will show it because in Rails by default primary key is `id`. If you overwrite the primary key, to something else, it will then show up that column. Look example:

```
Coupon.select(:active)
# Coupon Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "coupons"."active" FROM "coupons"
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Coupon active: true, code: nil>, #<Coupon active: true, code: nil>...
```

This is because in my Coupon model I have primary key set to `code`.

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'code'
  # ..
end
```

Although it is showing up in the *inspect* result, it is not there until, you are fetching it really. Now if you set up the `self.primary_key = ''` for testing, you will see that `#select` not showing anything. But don't set your `primary_key` to `''` like I did to remove the `id` display from `select` result. I just wanted to show from where it comes, nothing else.

```
Coupon.select(:active).order(:active)
# Coupon Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "coupons"."active" FROM "coupons"  ORDER BY "coupons"."active" ASC
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Coupon active: true>, #<Coupon active: true>...
```

Comment: The problem is that i need this primary key along the application, but in this specific case, i need return and array with the where condition, but that this result don't include the `id` field

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia It is just showing up the `id` in the inspection, but the actual result don't have the `id` value.